# Magento 2.3 upload_max_filesize max at 8M for import feature

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.3, file-upload

I adjusted `upload_max_filesize` in magento 2.3 and i can change the value to be anything between `2M` and `8M`.

If i put anything else like `85M`, `9M`, `50M`, etc the *Admin bar > System > Data Transfer > Import* prompt says

> Make sure your file isn't more than 8M.

It won't let me upload a file beyond that size even if it's set in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` or `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` after restarting `apache2` service.

Is this a bug in 2.3? How do i get around this for data imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must update `upload_max_filesize` AND `post_max_size` to be `>=` target upload size.